# PDFBox - read text from multiple PDFs and load it into multiple Text files

Tags: java, eclipse, pdf, pdfbox

I have more than 1000 pdf files in a folder , each one to be converted and saved in its corresponding text file .
I'm a bit new to Java and i'm using PDFBox to make the conversion ; I successfully got the code for one single pdf , but I'm stuck on how to do the conversion for all the PDFS in a single Folder. Can someone help me to achieve that in Java? .

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public final class ExtractPdf
{


public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException
{
    String fileName = "sample.pdf"; 
    PDDocument document = null;

    try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("out.txt"))
    {
        document = PDDocument.load( new File(fileName));
        PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
        String pdfText = stripper.getText(document).toString();
        System.out.println( "Text in the area:" + pdfText);
        out.println(pdfText);

    }
    finally
    {
        if( document != null )
        {
            document.close();
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Thanks, Free

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically your question is how to go through a directory…

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    File dir = new File("....");
    File[] files = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter()
    {
        // use anonymous inner class 
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name)
        {
            return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".pdf");
        }
    });
    // null check omitted!
    for (File file : files)
    {
        int len = file.getAbsolutePath().length();
        String txtFilename = file.getAbsolutePath().substring(0, len - 4) + ".txt";
        // check whether txt file exists omitted
        try (OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(txtFilename), Charsets.UTF_8);
             PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file))
        {
            PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
            stripper.writeText(document, out);
        }
    }
    // exception catch omitted. Add code here to avoid your whole job
    // dying if only one file is broken
}
```

Comment: After writing these lines I realize I should have flagged this as a duplicate, because this is likely to have been answered before… LOL... too late. Welcome to stackoverflow :-)

Comment: LOL I'm sorry , I tried to search for it but I missed it . I hope i didn't waste your time. Btw ur code was very useful , thank you very much and thanks for the welcome :-))

Comment: You're welcome. These things keep my brain working :-)

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Hello there, may i know how to get Charsets.UTF_8?
because im getting error, connot solve symblo for UTF_8

Comment: @Choy it is in org.apache.pdfbox.util.Charsets. If you don't have that then you're using an outdated version. Current version is 2.0.13.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr But, actually i don't understand your code, would you mind to explain it a bit to me?

Comment: Sorry but you'd need to ask a specific question, I can't go through this line by line. If the "anonymous inner class" part looks weird to you, then you need to enter this into a search engine or to look into a java book. (I don't mean to be nasty to you, really, it's a matter of time)